# Uiview crashing when loading with Uisearchbar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uisearchbar

I am designing a view with a search bar and whenever i load the view it crashes. The design is as follows

[image]

The error that i am getting is as follows

> ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setImage:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x153e646f0'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x182303164 0x18154c528 0x182310628 0x18bc7e188 0x182308b10 0x1821edccc 0x18b990b80 0x18b98f0d0 0x18be68870 0x18bffe380
>   0x18bffe4f8 0x18bffe0b8 0x18bb8b74c 0x18bffe380 0x18bffe4f8
>   0x18bffe0b8 0x18bb8b74c 0x18bffe380 0x18bffe0b8 0x18be506c8
>   0x18bffe380 0x18bffe4f8 0x18bffe0b8 0x18be4fa08 0x18bc2cbe0
>   0x18b9da8e8 0x18b8bd6a8 0x18b8bd5d8 0x18b9df878 0x18b9df564
>   0x18b9df3c0 0x18b9e1938 0x18ba953c8 0x18b8f25cc 0x18ba950f8
>   0x18b8f25cc 0x18b8f254c 0x18b8dd0f4 0x18be6180c 0x18b8f25cc
>   0x18b8f254c 0x18b8dd0f4 0x18b8f1e40 0x18bf4d5e4 0x18bf48b94
>   0x1822aacdc 0x1822a8694 0x1822a8c50 0x1821c8c58 0x184074f84
>   0x18b9215c4 0x100294ee8 0x181ce856c)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

View Controller Class Code is as follows

```
    import UIKit

class SearchStoreViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print ("Search Loaded")


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        //super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = DASHBOARD_SEARCH_VIEW_TITLE

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

After some research i found out that its the SearchBar that is causing the issue. The view loads fine if search bar is removed. Can anyone help me out to solve the problem.

Comment: currently u set any image in viewDidLoad

Comment: You can not set image to UIView. This is error due to setting image inside view.

Comment: I havent set any image to UIimageview

Comment: Show where you are setting an image?

Comment: @MahendraGP Nowhere

Comment: Have you added any constraints to search bar?

Comment: @Priya Yes, top = 0, left = 0, right = 0, height = 56

Comment: @JobinsJohn, please remove constraints and then try.

Comment: @Priya Tried and still crash occurs

Answer (score 0):

when you are setting an image from the search result, please verify that you are calling `seImage:` on `UIImageView` type not on `UIView` type.

> This error itself says that you are setting an image using UIView type object that is not possible, bcoz UIView doesn't has `setImage`

Also check `IBOutlet` connection whether it is connected to UIView or UIImageView.

Comment: I have added view controller code to the question. I havent set anything like that.

Comment: If i remove the search bar then the view loads perfectly. So i believe that is something related to SearchBar.

Comment: I think its related to result of search bar that you are trying to show...

Comment: Have you checked iboutlets ?

Comment: There are no iboutlets set

Comment: From the error....you are definitely setting `[UIView setImage:]` that is illegal..

Comment: how are you setting images and label shown in question?

Comment: Frankly i dont have any idea. I even tried quitting Xcode and restarting again

Answer (score 0):

You could trace which line causing crash by adding Exception breakpoint.

1. Go to Break point navigator (Cmd + 8)
2. Add Exception Breakpoint...

[image]

The crash is due to you are calling `setImage` method from a `UIView`'s object.

something like

```
[object setImage:image];
```

make sure that `object` is kind of `UIImageView`.

Comment: I havent set anything like that.

Comment: If i remove the search bar then the view loads perfectly. So i believe that is something related to SearchBar.

Also i am not doing anything in the view controller to add breakpoints. The view controller is almost in the initialisation stage.

Comment: You could trace which line causing crash by adding Exception breakpoint. Check updated answer

Comment: @JobinsJohn Go to Storyboard, click on `imageview`. Click `Identity Inspector`.  Make sure you didn't override it's class.

Comment: @LalKrishna I tried creating another view controller with just search bar and the issue is there.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. :(